# Facing scaling issues in autopilot cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, scaling, autopilot

I'm facing scaling issues in gke autopilot cluster. Getting error:

> node scale up failed:pod is at  risk of not being scheduled

I am facing this issue only with autopilot cluster

Try to do basic troubleshooting steps but issue not at sort out

Comment: Is it a persistent error, or only transient (solved after a while, 5 minutes or so)?

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere Persistent error only I will try below solution and it's seems helpful  to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-autopilot-clusters#scaling_issues), the mentioned  issue occurs when serial port logging is disabled in your Google Cloud project. GKE Autopilot clusters require serial port logging to effectively debug node issues. If serial port logging is disabled, Autopilot can't provision nodes to run your workloads.

> Serial port logging might be disabled at the organization level
> through an organization policy that enforces the
> compute.disableSerialPortLogging constraint. Serial port logging could
> also be disabled at the project or virtual machine (VM) instance
> level.
>
> **To resolve this issue do the following**:
>
> 1. Ask your Google Cloud organization policy administrator to [remove the compute.disableSerialPortLogging constraint](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/creating-managing-policies#boolean_constraints) in the project
>    with your Autopilot cluster.
> 2. If you don't have an organization policy that enforces this constraint, try to [enable serial port logging in your project
>    metadata.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/viewing-serial-port-output#setting_project_and_instance_metadata) This action requires the
>    compute.projects.setCommonInstanceMetadata IAM permission.

Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-autopilot-clusters) for more information about Troubleshooting
Autopilot clusters